# I think that the limit of $\frac{x-1}{xy-2x-y+2}$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,-2)$ exists, and equals $-1/4$. How to confirm this?

Tags: analysis, limits

This question is on a practice exam; unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve it!

Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{x-1}{xy-2x-y+2}.$$

Does the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,-2)$ exist? I think it does, because I've considered a few paths and they all go to $-1/4$. But, how can I prove this?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks, I'll be careful to avoid display size titles in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=\frac{x-1}{xy-2x-y+2}=\frac{x-1}{x(y-2)-(y-2)}=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(y-2)}=\frac{1}{y-2}$

$f(1,-2)=-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Note that the last cancellation only works when $x\neq 1$, which is fine because we are taking the limit as $x$ tends to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

At the core of Tomas's answer resides the following proposition:

> Let $f: X_f \to \Bbb R$ and $g: X_g \to \Bbb R$ be real-valued functions, defined on subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, such that $X_f \subseteq X_g$.
>
> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ agree on $X_f$ (we also say that $g$ is an *extension* of $f$), and let $\mathbf x_0$ be a limit point of $X_f$.
>
> Then if $\lim\limits_{\mathbf x \to\mathbf x_0} g(\mathbf x)$ exists, so does $\lim\limits_{\mathbf x \to\mathbf x_0} f(\mathbf x)$; moreover, these limits are equal.

In Tomas's answer, we have $f(x,y)$ as given, $X_f = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \ne -1, y \ne 2\}$; further, $g(x,y) = \frac1{y-2}$ and $X_g =\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: y \ne 2\}$.

Since $(x,y) = (1,-2) \in X_g$, and $g$ is continuous on $X_g$, the evaluation of the limit for $g$ becomes trivial.

---

I figured it was nice to have the general form of the proposition mentioned here, for this may help you to evaluate similar limits.